# execution is halt when reading excel file using apche poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

i'm trying to read excel file using Apache poi 3.8 version. also i use the dom4j 1.6.1 version. my pom.xml is below.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.8</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
 </dependency>
```

there is `<scope>provided</scope>` in the dom4j. when i remove the `<scope>provided</scope>` from pom and run the my sample code which mentioned below.

```
        FileInputStream inputStream1=new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\tmp\\"+event.getFile().getFileName()));
        Workbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream1);

        // Retrieving the number of sheets in the Workbook
        System.out.println("Workbook has " + workbook.getNumberOfSheets() + " Sheets : ");
        System.out.println(workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(0));
```

it works perfectly. now i really want add the `<scope>provided</scope>` into my pom.because it can't be changed in my project. so when i add that, the code lines are not executed and halt after initialize the `Workbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream1);` this code line.so what can i do?please help me anyone know about this. also i use the wildfly 11.0.0.Final version.thank you!

Comment: "want add the `<scope>provided</scope>` into my pom.because it can't be changed in my project"?? The `<scope>provided</scope>` means: We need this depencency at compile time but it should already be provided at run time. So we do not packaging that dependency because it will be already there at run time. If that fails, then the dependency is not already provided at run time and would had must be packaged.

Comment: @AxelRichter if i remove that `<scope>provided</scope>` from pom, there is an error when run the project `org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory`. so i can't remove it.

Comment: If I see something like `org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory` then my first suspicion would be that there are two different versions of `dom4j` while compile time versus run time. And those different versions are not compatible.

Comment: yes, i also thought that.to solve that problem, we must use the web server provided classes using `<scope>provided</scope>`. but the problem is when i use that it makes a problem such as halted the program execution when initializing XSSFWorkBook object.

Comment: [poi-ooxml 3.8](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/3.8) needs at least `dom4j 1.6.1`. So your provided version might be older? If I see something like that, then all in my mind screams !UPDATE!. The version 3.8 of apache poi is from 2012-03-26. Nobody should work with 6 years old software. And versions of dom4j less than version 1.6.1 must be older than February 2006. This is ancient.

Comment: hmm so, we close that problem!thank you!